# How do I deploy service fabric application from VSTS release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-service-fabric

I have configured a CI build for a Service Fabric application, in Visual Studio Team Services, according to this documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration

But instead of having my CI build do the publishing, I only perform the Build and Package tasks, and include all Service Fabric related output, such as pkg folder, scripts, publish profiles and application parameters, in the drop. This way I can pass it along to the new Release pipeline (agent-based releases) to do the actual deployment of my service fabric application.

In my release definition I have a single Azure Powershell task, that uses an ARM endpoint (with proper service principals configured).

When I deploy my app to an existing service fabric cluster, I use the default Deploy-FabricApplication cmdlet passing along the pkg folder and a publish profile that is configured with a connection to the existing cluster.

The release fails with an error message "Cluster connection instance is null". And I cannot understand why?

Doing some debugging I have found that:
The Deploy-FabricApplication cmdlet executes the Connect-ServiceFabricCluster cmdlet just fine, but as soon as the Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication cmdlet takes over execution, then the cluster connection is lost.

I would expect that this scenario is possible using the service fabric cmdlets, but I cannot figure out how to keep the cluster connection open during depoyment.

UPDATE: The link to the documentation no longer refers to the Service Fabric powershell scripts, so the pre-condition for this question is no longer documented. The article now refers to the VSTS build and release tasks, which can be prefered over the powershell cmdlets I tried to use.

Comment: Can you share the error logs? Did it always occurs? And which agent are you using? Usually, the cluster connection shouldn't lost when run Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication .

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When the `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` function is called (from Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1) a local `$clusterConnection` variable is set after the call to `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`. You can see that using `Get-Variable`.

Unfortunately there is logic in some of the SDK scripts that expect that variable to be set but because they run in a different scope, that local variable isn't available.

It works in Visual Studio because the Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 script is called using [dot source notation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847849.aspx), which puts the `$clusterConnection` variable in the current scope.

I'm not sure if there is a way to use dot sourcing when running a script though the release pipeline but you could, as a workaround, make the `$clusterConnection` variable global right after it's been set via the `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` call. Edit your `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` script and add the following line after the connection logic (~line 169):

```
$global:clusterConnection = $clusterConnection
```

By the way, you might want to consider setting up [custom build/release tasks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task) that deploy a Service Fabric application, rather than using the various Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 scripts.

Comment: Thx for the explanation, will try it out soon, and I had an idea that this was due to some powershell variable scoping issue. 

I'll look into the custom build tasks, once I have a functional release pipeline up and running. 

I started with the Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 since it was mentioned and used in the documentation that I linked to.

Comment: Accept this answer

Comment: THANKS @charisk. :D

Comment: @charisk, Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 does not define or use $ClusterConnection anywhere (you can do full text search on entire folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\. It's the Connect-ServiceFabricCluster which defines this variable and some SDK functions seem to be depending on it (ones which require connection present). See https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/137

Answer (score 2):

There now exists a built-in VSTS task for deploying a Service Fabric app so you no longer need to bother with executing the PowerShell script on your own.  Task documentation page is at https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/deploy/service-fabric-deploy.  The original CI article has also been updated which provides details on how to set everything up: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration/.

Comment: Saw it a couple days ago, I am really exited since I suggested it on uservoice a couple of month ago. Great work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "PowerShell" task instead of "Azure PowerShell" task.

Comment: Using the "pure" powershell build task made sure that the script was executed using the . (dot) notation which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same bug today and opened a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/137)

On a side note, VS generated script `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` uses module

`"$((Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric SDK" -Name "FabricSDKPSModulePath").FabricSDKPSModulePath)\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1"`

That's where `Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication` comes from. You can check the deployment logic and rewrite it in more sane way using lower-level ServiceFabric SDK cmdlets (potentially getting connection using `Get-ServiceFabricClusterConnection` instead of global-ling it)