# Publish to Service Fabric Cluster fails because of Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I am using the Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 script that is generated when you create a Service Fabric project to deploy my application.

When deploying to a Service Fabric cluster I can deploy locally if I first connect to a local cluster using `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`. However, my build server does not run a local cluster instance so I am unable to first connect to a local instance. When I connect with `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ClusterConnectionParameters` I get data back on the connection that it was successful. When it gets to the publish and runs the Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection command I get the following error.

```
WARNING: Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection : Cluster connection instance is null
At C:\ProgramFiles\MicrosoftSDKs\ServiceFabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:129 char:16
+         [void](Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection)
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestClusterConnection
```

I have tried removing Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection from the Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1 module and I get a different set of errors. No matter what I have tried to this point, if I first connect to a cluster it works but not if I connect via the powershell script.

Update! Solved
Solved this using dot sourcing: [How do I deploy service fabric application from VSTS release pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711540/how-do-i-deploy-service-fabric-application-from-vsts-release-pipeline)

Comment: Your title says `Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection`, but your error message says `Get-ServiceFabricApplication`, so which is it? How is `$ApplicationName` populated? How is `@ClusterConnectionParameters` populated? Where do you call `Connect-ServerFabricCluster`?

Comment: what happens if you call 'Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ClusterConnectionParameters' with the same parameter settings from your dev machine?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I revised my question

Comment: @LoekD If I first connect to the server manually using Connect-ServiceFabricCluster and then run the script it works. All with the same parameters (ServerCertThumbprint, X509Credential, etc.). If I don't manually connect then I get the same instance is null issue

Comment: Update! Solved it with dot sourcing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711540/how-do-i-deploy-service-fabric-application-from-vsts-release-pipeline

Comment: What exactly did you change in your command when you used dot sourcing?

Comment: I don't have it in front of me @TolaOdejayi but something like this on the build server
powershell.exe . Deploy.ps1 ---ApplicationPackagePath .\Release ...

Comment: @KenWin0x539 couldnt you answer your own question with a proper answer rather than comments? :-)  I'm also having a similar problem and running Connect-ServerFabricCluster seems to fix it (I'm deploying to a local SF cluster)

Answer (score 3):

Set `$global:clusterConnection = $clusterConnection` after calling `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` or call `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` using the [dot source notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1#using-dot-source-notation-with-scope).

The call to `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` sets a `$clusterConnection` variable on the local Powershell scope, which gets lost when calling other scopes. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711540/how-do-i-deploy-service-fabric-application-from-vsts-release-pipeline) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the certificate is installed correctly on your machine. I faced similar issue and installed the certificate and it worked. Also verify the store location is correctly set to

StoreLocation="LocalMachine"

if you installed certificate on local machine else set it to   StoreLocation="CurrentUser"

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was changing from 
`$clusterConnection = Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $ClusterConnectionParameters.ConnectionEndpoint -ErrorAction Stop`

to

`Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $ClusterConnectionParameters.ConnectionEndpoint -ErrorAction Stop`