# Invoke PowerShell from cmd, context gets lost when that PowerShell calls into another module

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I have a PowerShell script which calls into ServiceFabricSDK PowerShell module to trigger Azure Service Fabric Application Deployment. All works fine when I call that PowerShell directly, but if I call it from a `cmd` file using `powershell` command, things get messed up and it looks like some context gets lost between my PowerShell script and the module it calls into.

Here's what I mean:

My PowerShell script takes application name and couple more parameters, imports `ServiceFabricSDK.psm1`, runs `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` to connect to local Service Fabric cluster and ultimately invokes `Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication` to start the deployment:

```
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $applicationName,

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $repoTargetPath,

    [Switch]
    $retail,

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $targetEnvironment = "dev.local"
)

# Load ServiceFabricSDK first
Write-Output "Loading Service Fabric SDK module"
Import-Module "$ENV:ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1"

# Connect to the local cluster
Write-Output "Connecting to local Service Fabric cluster"
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster | Out-Null
Write-Output "Successfully connected to local Service Fabric cluster"

$repoTargetPath = $repoTargetPath.TrimEnd('\')
$target = if($retail.IsPresent) { "retail" } Else { "debug" }
$applicationTargetBasePath = "$repoTargetPath\distrib\$target\applications\$applicationName"
$applicationPackagePath = "$applicationTargetBasePath\package\"
$applicationParametersFilePath = "$applicationTargetBasePath\applicationParameters\$applicationName.$targetEnvironment.xml"

Write-Output "Deploying application $applicationName to local Service Fabric cluster"

# Deploy the application
Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationPackagePath $applicationPackagePath -ApplicationParameterFilePath $applicationParametersFilePath -ApplicationName "fabric:/$applicationName" -OverwriteBehavior Always -Verbose -SkipPackageValidation
```

If I run it directly it all works fine:

```
PS G:\repo> .\build\scripts\Deploy-Application.ps1 -applicationName HelloWorld -targetEnvironment "dev.local" -repoTargetPath G:\repo\target\
Loading Service Fabric SDK module
Connecting to local Service Fabric cluster
WARNING: Cluster connection with the same name already existed, the old connection will be deleted
Successfully connected to local Service Fabric cluster
Validating the package and application parameters
Deploying application HelloWorld to local Service Fabric cluster
An application with name 'fabric:/HelloWorld' already exists in the cluster with Application Type 'HelloWorldType' and Version '1.0.20170816-seed-1    207928760'. Removing it.
Remove application instance succeeded
Unregister application type succeeded.
Copying application to image store...
Copy application package succeeded
Registering application type...
Register application type succeeded
Removing application package from image store...
Remove application package succeeded
Creating application...

ApplicationName        : fabric:/HelloWorld
ApplicationTypeName    : HelloWorldType
ApplicationTypeVersion : 1.0.20170816-seed-1207928760
ApplicationParameters  : { "HelloWorldServiceType_InstanceCount" = "2" }

Create application succeeded.
```

I also have `appStart.cmd` file which calls into that PowerShell:

```
@if "%_echo%"=="" echo off

pushd
cd %BaseDir%

if "%1" == "" goto error

echo powershell %ScriptsPath%\Deploy-Application.ps1 -applicationName "%1" -repoTargetPath "%BaseDir%\\target\\" -targetEnvironment "dev.local"
call powershell %ScriptsPath%\\Deploy-Application.ps1 -applicationName "%1" -repoTargetPath "%BaseDir%\\target\\" -targetEnvironment "dev.local"

GOTO :EOF
```

There is nothing more than just calling into that PowerShell, but unfortunately the deployment fails, because the module sees no cluster connection:

```
G:\repo>appStart HelloWorld
powershell G:\repo\build\scripts\Deploy-Application.ps1 -applicationName "HelloWorld" -repoTargetPath "G:\repo\\target\\" -targetEnvironment "dev.local"
Loading Service Fabric SDK module
Connecting to local Service Fabric cluster
Successfully connected to local Service Fabric cluster
Validating the package and application parameters
Deploying application HelloWorld to local Service Fabric cluster
VERBOSE: System.NullReferenceException: Cluster connection instance is null
WARNING: Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
Get-ServiceFabricClusterConnection : Cluster connection instance is null
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service
Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:144 char:1
+ Get-ServiceFabricClusterConnection
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-ServiceFabricClusterConnection], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.GetClusterConnection
```

I played with it and `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` result can be checked by `Get-ServiceFabricClusterConnection`, which is what `Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1` is doing. I can run it in my PowerShell right before calling into `Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1` and it returns the right connection data, even when run from `appStart.cmd`. **Why is the connection lost when called into the script?**

Comment: Depending on the PowerShell version you run, what happens when you add the [-MTA or -STA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta) parameter: `call powershell -MTA %ScriptsPath%\\Deploy-Application.ps1 -applicationName "%1" -repoTargetPath "%BaseDir%\\target\\" -targetEnvironment "dev.local"`

Comment: @iRon Made no difference.

Comment: Try the pattern:

`powershell -Command { %ScriptsPath%\\Deploy-Application.ps1 -applicationName \"%1\" -repoTargetPath \"%BaseDir%\\target\\\" -targetEnvironment \"dev.local\" }`

Comment: @MaxBurlik Didn't work, and now I'm not getting the output of the PowerShell script piped back to regular command line, so I can't see what the error message is.

Comment: When you import the ServiceFabricSDK.psm1 module do you have any additional configuration to say connect to the service fabric cluster? If it is normally part of your profile and you're running this with a new account that never connected to it then maybe that could be your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting the cluster connection into a global variable after `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`:

```
$global:clusterConnection = $clusterConnection
```

More info here [How do I deploy service fabric application from VSTS release pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711540/how-do-i-deploy-service-fabric-application-from-vsts-release-pipeline)